# How should i determine of the apple can be placed in a specific location?

Tags: javascript

```
function Apple() {
  this.x = 0;
  this.y = 0;

  this.show = function() {
    fill(255, 0, 0);
    noStroke();
    rect(this.x, this.y, scl, scl);
  }

  this.create = function() {
    var cols = fieldWidth/scl;
    var rows = fieldHeight/scl;

    do {
      this.x = floor(random(cols))*scl+15;
      this.y = floor(random(rows))*scl+30;
    } while (!empty());

  }

  function empty() {
    for (var i = 0; i < s.body.length; i++) {
      if (this.x == s.body[i].x & this.y == s.body[i].y) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  }
}
```

this is the code for the apple object in my snake game. the empty() function is used to ensure the apple doesn't spawn inside of the snake in the create() function. at the moment it does not work how would i fix it?

Comment: does not work as in no errors but it still spawns inside the snakes body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you mistyped the Logical AND operator.
You should use `&&` instead of `&`

Here is how your code should be:

```
function Apple() {
  this.x = 0;
  this.y = 0;

  this.show = function() {
    fill(255, 0, 0);
    noStroke();
    rect(this.x, this.y, scl, scl);
  }

  this.create = function() {
    var cols = fieldWidth/scl;
    var rows = fieldHeight/scl;

    do {
      this.x = floor(random(cols))*scl+15;
      this.y = floor(random(rows))*scl+30;
    } while (!empty());

  }

  function empty() {
    for (var i = 0; i < s.body.length; i++) {
      if (this.x == s.body[i].x && this.y == s.body[i].y) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: false & false == 0, false & true = 0, true & true = 1 ... 0 is falsey, 1 is truthy, so that is not the issue at all

Comment: after i changed it, the apple can no longer spawn inside of the snakes body.

Comment: ahhhh ... poorly formatted code is poorly formatted (original post) totally misread the code